# Why the iterator on map.vaules can be used to remove HashMap#Entry?

Tags: java, hashmap, iterator

I'm trying to remove all the entry of which the value is `null`. The code is:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("one", null);
map.put("two", null);
map.put("three", "THREE");

Iterator iterator = map.values().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext())
{
    if (iterator.next() == null) {
        iterator.remove();
    }
}

for (Map.Entry<String, String> e : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(e.getKey() + ":" + e.getValue());
}
```

My question is `iterator` is bind to `map.values`, why it can remove the whole entry?

Comment: Just to confirm, your code works but you're trying to understand why. Correct?

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to find the root cause.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible because `Map#values` returns a view of the values that is **backed by the map**.

From the official [Java-Doc of Map#values](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values--):

> Returns a Collection view of the values contained in this map. The collection is backed by the map, so changes to the map are reflected in the collection, and vice-versa. [...] The collection supports element removal, which removes the corresponding mapping from the map, via the Iterator.remove, Collection.remove, removeAll, retainAll and clear operations. It does not support the add or addAll operations.

---

Note that the `AbstractMap` class, from which most map implementations extend, has an extra field `transient volatile Collection<V> values` and that is exactly what you will get there. As you see the collection is internally used by the Map and thus changes on it are also reflected on the Map itself. See also: [Source code of AbstractMap](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractMap.java?av=h#AbstractMap)

---

If you like to go in detail, take a look at the `AbstractMap#values` method in the source code. There they create the *values*-collection as a wrapper that operates on the original map. For example its `next` method iterates on the entries `Entry<K, V>` of the Map but only return their value with `Entry#getValue` and so on.
Also the `remove` method, as you can see, gets passed over to the iterator of `Entry<K, V>`, thus the remove will in the end be executed on the original map again.

Answer (score 2):

Explanations have been given by Zabuza, but because there is proper way to remove your elements, I write them :

---

To remove `Entry` with null value you can use `Streams` :

```
map = map.entrySet()
         .stream()
         .filter(entry -> entry.getValue()!=null)
         .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Or in **one - line** :    `map.entrySet().removeIf(e -> e.getValue()==null);`

Or : `map.values().removeIf(v -> v == null)`

Comment: Or `map.values().removeIf(v -> v == null)`. But I think you missed the point of the question.

Comment: @shmosel yes I just realize ^^

Comment: @azro @shmosel , from the code of `Collection.removeIf`, I think basically `removeIf` method is same as the method used in my sample code, both are based on `iterator`.

Comment: @caisil Indeed it is. It's just a more concise version of what you're doing.